# Ruby: unable to open image `"mask.png"'

Tags: ruby, image, sass, compass-sass, rmagick

If I say that the file call 'mask.png' than this code works:

```
#imageColor.rb
require 'RMagick'
include Magick

module Sass::Script::Functions
  def imagetest(sourceFile, targetFile, sourceColor, targetColor)       
    sources = Image.read('mask.png')
    target = sources[0].opaque('black', 'blue')
    target.write('test.png') 
    Sass::Script::String.new("#00ff00")
  end
end
```

---

```
#_imageColor.scss
@mixin image-color($source, $target, $sourceColor, $targetColor)
{
  color: imagetest($source, $target, $sourceColor, $targetColor);
}
```

---

```
#ie.scss
@import "theme/default/ie/ie";
@import "imageColor";  
body {
  @include image-color('mask.png', 'test.png', '#000000', '#ff0000');   
}
```

If I say that in the method image-color (in ie.scss) the file call 'mask.png' than this code doesn't works:

```
#imageColor.rb
require 'RMagick'
include Magick

module Sass::Script::Functions
  def imagetest(sourceFile, targetFile, sourceColor, targetColor)       
    sources = Image.read(sourceFile)
    target = sources[0].opaque(sourceColor, targetColor)
    target.write(targetFile) 
    Sass::Script::String.new("#00ff00")
  end
end
```

Error:

```
unable to open image `"mask.png"': No such file or directory
```

Do you know why?

Comment: What happens if you put the image in the same folder as the scss file?

Comment: ...the same error. Problem is not in the path. It find the image, but it want not to open it...

Comment: try just passing mask.png w/out the ticks...looks like it may be wrapping your quotes in quotes

Comment: ...than come this error: Invalid CSS after "...mage-color(mask": expected ")", was ".png, 'test.png...")

Answer (score 0):

I have add this to imageColor.rb:

```
source_file  = [sourceFile,".png"].join("")
target_file  = [targetFile,".png"].join("")        
source_color = [sourceColor].join("")        
target_color = [targetColor].join("")
```